# How to draw this figure with only 2 loops and 1 if statement in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop, logic, puzzle

How could I draw such a figure with 2 for loops and 1 if statement in C?

```
AAAAA
AAAAB
AAABB
AAAAB
AAAAA
```

I know I'd have to compare the rows and columns but I don't know how to get the exact result.

**It has to work for every number larger than 0 and smaller than 24.**

What I did so far is the following:

```
for (row = 1; row <= n; row++)
{
    for (column = 1; column <= n; column++)
    {
        if ( row >= column )
        {
            printf("A");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("B");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

which gives me this for n = 5:

```
ABBBB
AABBB
AAABB
AAAAB
AAAAA
```

Comment: _"I Know I'd have to...."_ all in air ? Try something and then come back here for clarification/doubts/errors

Comment: I added the general case in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here you go:

```
for (row = 1; row <= 5; row++)
{
    for (column = 1; column <= 5; column++)
    {
        if ( (row < column) && (column > 5 - row + 1) )
        {
            printf("B");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("A");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zz2RY/16/)

explanation :

condition `(row < column)` 'draws':

```
ABBBB
AABBB
AAABB
AAAAB
AAAAA
```

condition `(column > 5 - row + 1)` 'draws' :

```
AAAAA
AAAAB
AAABB
AABBB
ABBBB
```

the combination of these condition is you result.

Comment: It has to work for every number larger than 0 and smaller than 24.

Comment: So change the occurrences of 5 to `n`.  And don't leave crucial points out of the question; it isn't fair to those who are trying to help you.

Comment: Oh the joys of moving specifications. A career in project management certainly awaits you.

Comment: I just tried it again, and with this solution it only works correct if the number is even. It doesn't work correctly when the number is uneven since in the middle you do not have a single B but two Bs.

Comment: whats the output for uneven nummber ? give example for n=6

Comment: Formulation of the problem is a bit ambiguous, your solution is correct.

Answer (score 3):

python code(translated to C below):

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        if(i-j<0 and i+j>4):
            print("B",end="")
        else:
            print("A",end="")
    print()
```

C:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
   {
       if(i-j<0 && i+j>4) printf("B");
       else printf("A");
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Do you remember x=y and x=-y lines in geometry? Solution is the intersection of the half planes.

Check [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y-x%3C0%20and%20x%2by%3E4) out for geometrical idea behind it.

UPDATE:
You also indicated that it should work for general cases, so:

```
int n = SIZE;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
   {
       if(i-j<0 && i+j>(2*(n/2)) printf("B");
       else printf("A");
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Of course, but I solved using geometry so It better represents the idea of lines.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way; note how I've exploited the symmetry of the output to run the row counter from -2 to +2. My counting `col` backwards is a little naughty although it makes the `if` and the `abs` clearer.

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
    for (int row = -2; row <= +2; ++row){
        for (int col = 5; col >= 1; --col){
            if (col > 2 - abs(row)){
                printf("A");
            } else {
                printf("B");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Note that you'll need at least C99 to compile this due to my placement of `int` inside the `for` loops.

Answer (score 1):

Single loop:

```
for(i=0; i<30; ++i) putch(i%6==5?'\n':i%6-(i/6-2)*(i/6-2)<3?'a':'b');
```

Comment: Nice! But this needs another `for` and an `if` -- because that is the assignment. `if(true)` at the front works, but what about a for..loop ... without introducing an unnecessary unused variable?

Answer (score 0):

Following may not be as efficient as others but you can simply generate patterns analyzing the symmetry

```
                        n=9
                n=7     0
        n=5     0       1
AAAAA   0       1       2
AAAAB   1       2       3
AAABB   2       3       4
AAAAB   1       2       3
AAAAA   0       1       2
                0       1
                        0
```

So :

```
void generate_AB(int n, int i)
{
 int j;
   for(j=1;j<=n-i;j++) //n-i no. of As
      printf("A"); 
   for(j=1;j<=i;j++) // i no. of Bs
      printf("B");
      printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
  int i,j,n=5;

    for(i=0;i<=n/2;i++)  // Count 0 to INT(n/2)
        generate_AB(n,i);

    for(i=n/2-1;i>=0;i--) // Count  INT(n/2)-1 to 0
        generate_AB(n,i);

    return 0;
}
```